# editMode change not recognized in a TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

This code works perfectly when not in a `TabView`. Once it is placed in a `TabView`, the `.editMode` change does not appear to have any effect on the `List`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            myView().tabItem {
             Text("test")
            }.tag(0)
        }
    }
}
struct myView : View {
    @State var list = ["a", "b", "c"]
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                if self.editMode?.wrappedValue == .active {
                    self.editMode?.wrappedValue = .inactive
                } else {
                    self.editMode?.wrappedValue = .active
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Edit")
            })
            List {
                ForEach(list, id:\.self) {val in
                    Text(val)
                }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    ()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is a bug, or if the `.editMode` is somehow different when in a `TabView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly inject the `editMode`:

```
struct myView: View {
    @State var list = ["a", "b", "c"]
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                if self.editMode?.wrappedValue == .active {
                    self.editMode?.wrappedValue = .inactive
                } else {
                    self.editMode?.wrappedValue = .active
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Edit")
            })
            List {
                ForEach(list, id: \.self) { val in
                    Text(val)
                }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    ()
                })
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, editMode) // <- inject here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can toggle editing mode for your list view by adding an `EditButton`

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var list = ["a", "b", "c"]

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          List {
              ForEach(list, id: \.self) { value in
                  Text(value)
              }
              .onDelete(perform: delete)
          }
          .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
      }
  }

  func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
     list.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `EditButton()` instead of creating a normal `Button`

This worked for me :

```
VStack {
  EditButton()
  List {
   ForEach(list, id:\.self) {val in
     Text(val)
   }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
     ()
   })
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom `EditMode` variable and injecting it into the relevant child views—including the `EditButton`, to avoid rolling your own—solves this issue.

**Tested on iOS 17.2**

[Example GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmJSf.gif)

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditButtonTabView: View {
  @State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      NavigationStack {
        List {
          ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { number in
            Text(String(number))
          }
          .onDelete { _ in
            // Delete action
          }
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        .toolbar {
          EditButton()
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
      }
      .tabItem {
        Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
      }
    }
  }
}
```